# App not listed in Motion & Fitness page despite the add of NSMotionUsageDescription

Tags: ios, xcode

I've added `NSMotionUsageDescription` key in `info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needed for Pedometer</string>
```

But my app isn't listed on the **Privacy > Motion & Fitness** page. What am I doing wrong here?

PS: I'm coming from Android background and I believe I don't need to request this permission in order for it to appear on that page.

Comment: You need to request access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply having the key in Info.plist doesn't mean that your app actually uses motion data.

The permission request is shown by iOS when attempt to access motion data using, for example, `CMPedometer`. Once you have attempted to access the pedometer data and iOS has collected a response (allow or deny) from the user, your app will appear in the privacy settings.  This allows the user to grant or revoke access.